# tightVNC often crashes when pressing Alt-Tab (on ubunt 16.04, Xfce4)

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys, vnc, tightvncserver

I recently received a new ubuntu 16.04 machine.
I installed tightVNC server and acccessing it using RealVNC from my windows 10 machine. For window manger, I'm using Xfce4. But when I press alt-tab (set to switch windows), very often the VNC is disconnected and I have restart the VNC connection (remove /tmp/.X1-lock and /tmp/.X11-unix .. and vncserver -geometry.. :1).
And this happens so often this morning and drives me crazy. I used to use centos and I expected everything will be breeze in installing but I seem to have more problems in ubuntu 16.4. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I tried vino before but it was ok. (but vino provides no separate screen, it's actual screen on the console, and it was rather slow, so I switched to tightvnc). I'll try other vnc server tomorrow like vnc4server which I'm using on my CentOs machine with no problem.

Comment: @dsstorefile1 I just installed vnc4server and tested some, it looks it works just fine. With the same test this morning, tightvnc crashes all the same..so I'll use vnc4server from now on. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I'm also encountering these crashes when pressing Alt-Tab quickly, on Ubuntu 16.04 with tightvncserver 1.3.10-0ubuntu3, running Gnome classic (metacity window manager). Here's the [stack trace](https://gist.github.com/inkarkat/19fa1eb0f22a78de40387372f3156193) if anyone wants to report this.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed vnc4server and it looks it works just fine.
When I resize the web browser violently, it doesn't crash.
Definately tightvnc seems to have a bug.

I did
`sudo apt-get install vnc4server`
to install vnc4server, and

`sudo update-alternatives --config vncserver`
and selected vnc4server in the list.

Comment: I've also tried `vnc4server`, but window decorations were missing completely until I did `metacity --restart`, and then icons were different and fonts looked wrong. For me VNC access is a temporary stopgap solution, so I'm back to TightVNC and avoiding Alt-Tab.